# A Fact I Observed While Looking at the Proof of Pythagorean Theorem.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a right angled triangle, where the right angle is at $A$.
Construct squares on $AC$, $AB$ and $BC$ as shown. Let $P$ be the point of intersection of $BK$ and $FC$ (Note that $P$ is not marked in the figure).

> Then I conjecture that $AP$ is parallel to $BD$.

[image]

**What I tried:**

By observing that $\Delta FBC\cong \Delta ABD$, we see that $\angle BAC=\angle BFC$. 
Therefore, if $X$ is the point of intersection of $FC$ and $AD$, we see that $BFAX$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.

This gives us that $AD\perp FC$, and similarly $BK\perp AE$. But I couldn't go any further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Fig.1]

By considering the congruent (and similar) right angle triangles it is easy to prove (similar to as you did) that $BK\bot MC$, $CF\bot BM$ and $MA\bot BC$. All three height of the triangle $MBC$ cross in one point ($=P$), thus $AP\bot BC$.

Comment: This seems great. I still haven't figured out why $MP$ should pass through $A$ though.

Comment: There is no $P$ from the beginning. We take three heights $BK, CF$ and $MA$ (continued to the side $BC$). They must cross in *one* point. Call the point $P$. So $MA$ *goes though the cross-point* of two green lines and *is orthogonal* to $BC$.

Comment: Forget my comment. It was a bit hasty. Thanks.

Comment: @caffeinemachine You are welcome, and thanks for the nice problem.

Comment: No. Thanks for the masterful solution!